# How do I open a Flash CS6 file in CS5

Tags: cs6, cs5, adobe-flash

I know that in CS6, you can save as CS5. But right now, I'm at school on the computers in my design class. I have a file that I made at home in CS6, but I need to open it on my school's computers that have CS5. How can I do this?

If I can't do this, can anyone do it for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can try with [**Flannel**](http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2012/03/06/flannel-open-newer-fla-files/).

Just drag and drop your Flash CS6 `FLA` file onto Flannel and it will make a copy and append _CS5 to the file name. That file can be opened in Flash CS5.

Intro paragraph from the above linked page:

> Since the FLA format is now XML- and ZIP-based, it’s relatively easy
>   to unzip the package, open a file, and set the version back so that
>   the file can be opened in Flash CS5.

Comment: Can it really be that easy? I wonder if there will be features or tags which cs5 won't know how to handle? Anyway, its a good do-it-yourself way to try it.

Answer (score 1):

In Illustrator, when you save a file it asks you which version you want to save it as.  Instead of CS6, you can choose a “Legacy Format” like Illustrator CS5, but be aware that you may lose some newer features and attributes when the document is read back in to the prior release.

In Flash Professional, you can save in XFL or FLA format for CS5.5 or CS5, although you may lose some newer features.